facing WalletSendTransactionError: Unexpected error
**this is the error i am facing while creating the token **
WalletSendTransactionError: Unexpected error
at StandardWalletAdapter.sendTransaction (adapter.js:224:23)
at async Object.eval [as sendTransaction] (WalletProviderBase.js:161:16)

this is the code
const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: mintkeyPair.publicKey,
        space: MINT_SIZE,
        lamports,
        programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
      }),
      createInitializeMetadataPointerInstruction(
        mintkeyPair.publicKey,
        wallet.publicKey,
        mintkeyPair.publicKey,
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
      ),
      createInitializeMintInstruction(
        mintkeyPair.publicKey,
        decimals,
        wallet.publicKey,
        null,
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
      ),
      createInitializeInstruction({
        programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        mint: mintkeyPair.publicKey,
        metadata: mintkeyPair.publicKey,
        name: metaData.name,
        symbol: metaData.symbol,
        uri: metaData.uri,
        mintAuthority: wallet.publicKey,
        updateAuthority: wallet.publicKey,
      })
    );

    

    transaction.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;
    transaction.recentBlockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash;
    transaction.sign(mintkeyPair);

    console.log(transaction)

    const signature = await wallet.sendTransaction(transaction, connection, { preflightCommitment: 'processed' });
    await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, 'processed');

repo link:link

could you set {skipPreflight: true} and share an explorer link to the failing IX

This is a guess, but MINT_SIZE is probably not enough to cover for the base mint + metadata pointer extension + metadata extension, or there aren't enough lamports passed in to cover rent-exemption when the metadata is initialized.
Feel free to start from the metadata example at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/js/examples/metadata.ts and customize from there.
